# When I bind the mousemove Event to the parent ,how to stop the child to response the mousemove event?

Tags: jquery, mousemove

```
<div id="father" style="top:10px;left:10px;width:500px;height:500px">
  <div id="child" style="position:relative;top:50px;left:50px;width:100px;height:100px">    
  </div>
</div>

$("#father").mousemove(function(){
   alert("out");
})
```

How do I only bind the mousemove event on the parent, not inherit the child?
When I move the mouse in the parent layer, I can call the function but not in the child layer.  PS:I don't need the mouseout event on the child layer as could have many neighboring child layers. The crossing event between the child layers do not need to trigger the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript has mouseenter, but you're title and description is talking about mousemove..so i assume you meant mousemove. One way you can handle this is to bind the function to a mousemouse event only if the parent has a certain class. Like 'active' and remove the class active from the parent when the mouse goes over the child.

**[Here is a fiddle to test](http://jsfiddle.net/A6eE7/)**

```
$('#child').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active')
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active')
});
$('body').delegate("#father.active", "mousemove", function() {
    console.log("moving");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to block the events from the children from propagating back to the parents.

```
$("#child").mouseenter(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: I works better when I try.This prevent the mouseleave event to happen again and again.Thanks for your help!